# How can I synchronize a received image which is updated every 20 milliseconds?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I am using c++ and handling the asynchronous calls with boost. I have a main function, which calls the image processor every 20 milliseconds, and using OpenCV I am trying to show the image I am getting from another program.

The main function looks like this:

```
 void Master::StartControlTimer()
 {
     m_ControlTimer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds( m_ControlTimerPeriod ));

     m_ControlTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Master::OnControlTimerElapsed, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
 }
```

The OnControlTimerElapsed calls a function, which receives an image from a program, and I want to process the image, and display it using OpenCV:

```
void ImageProcessor::processImage(unsigned char* image, int resolution[2])
{
  m_OcvImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(resolution[0], resolution[1]), 8, 3);

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < resolution[1]; i++){
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < resolution[0]; j++){
        int r, g, b;
        r = cvRound(255 * image[3 * ((resolution[1] - i)*resolution[0] + j) + 0]);
        g = cvRound(255 * image[3 * ((resolution[1] - i)*resolution[0] + j) + 1]);
        b = cvRound(255 * image[3 * ((resolution[1] - i)*resolution[0] + j) + 2]);

        m_OcvImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b((uchar)b, (uchar)g, (uchar)r);

    }
  }
  cv::namedWindow("image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::imshow("image", m_OcvImage);
  m_OcvImage.release();
}
```

My problem is that this is throwing me an R6010 error, and I think this happens because it is trying to write to the same memory location, since the processImage is being called every 20 milliseconds.

How could I synchronize the image using boost library?

I tried using:

```
 boost::mutex::scoped_lock lok(m_ImageMutex)
```

where m_ImageMutex was a boost::mutex, right before the cvCreateImage function was called, but no luck with that.

Any helpful idea?

Comment: 1. *avoid* deprecated c-api calls, like cvCreateImage, stick with cv::Mat. 2. move `cv::namedWindow("image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);` out of the processImage into main. 3. if you use imshow(), you need a waitKey() (and that preferably in the main thread)

Comment: Just stating the obvious, but when using the `boost::mutex`, you have to lock the mutex when you copy the image in your `processImage` function and unlock it after the copy (e.g. using the `scoped_lock`, as you did) and also when you write on the image buffer. If you do not lock the mutex when writing on the image buffer, the behavior is the same as when you do not use any mutex.

Comment: @berak can you please write it as an answer, so I can accept it? It really helped me. I was stuck here for more than a week. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- stick with the c++ api and avoid mixing in deprecated c-api calls like `cvCreateImage`, so that would be :

  ```
  m_OcvImage = Mat(Size(resolution[0], resolution[1]), CV_8UC3);
  ```
- move the `cv::namedWindow()` call into main. you don't need to create a new window for every call to `processImage()`
- if you use `imshow()`, you need a corresponding `waitKey()` call (and that preferably in the main thread)

[aaand, - what @AldurDisciple said above.. multithreading without any locks is like juggling knives blindfolded. you don't want to miss a beat.. ]